# How to add slim to rails statistics (stats) for code statistics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I attempted to search and experiment, but I couldn't determine how to incorporate Slim into Ruby on Rails' statistics for views. Currently, it only counts `.erb` templates, whereas I also want `.slim` files to be included since they are also considered views.

```bash
% bin/rails stats
+----------------------+--------+--------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Name                 |  Lines |    LOC | Classes | Methods | M/C | LOC/M |
+----------------------+--------+--------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Controllers          |   3245 |   1634 |      57 |     218 |   3 |     5 |
| Helpers              |    186 |    149 |       0 |      18 |   0 |     6 |
| Jobs                 |     34 |     20 |       2 |       2 |   1 |     8 |
| Models               |    879 |    541 |      25 |      77 |   3 |     5 |
| Mailers              |     85 |     53 |       3 |       6 |   2 |     6 |
| Channels             |     46 |     28 |       3 |       4 |   1 |     5 |
| Views                |      0 |      0 |       0 |       0 |   0 |     0 |
+----------------------+--------+--------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
```

I could add an extra rules for something like "Slim views", but this would count the `.erb` templates in views too.

Comment: Add gem "slim" and bunlde or gem install slim

Comment: @LihnNguyen  It's not what I've been asking for. I've added more information to make the question more clear.